# No operator "*" matches these operands

Tags: c++, fundamentals-ts

this is my code

```
glm::vec3 v(4, -6, 7);

glm::vec3 twiceV = 2 * v;
```

I have included glm Stable and experimental glm extensions.
Why I cannot use `int * vec`?

Comment: Is there a free function providing support for 2 * v in glm? Try v * 2, so you actually call operator* on vec3.

Comment: What does the 'fundamentals-ts' tag have to do with this?

Answer (score 2):

`2` is an integer, while the elements of a `glm::vec3` are floats. Try this instead:

```
glm::vec3 twiceV = 2.0f * v;
```

I would also pass floating-point values to the constructor (`4.0f`), just to make it explicit that you're dealing with floats.

Alternatively, you can use an integer vector `glm::ivec3`:

```
glm::ivec3 v(4, -6, 7);
glm::ivec3 twiceV = 2 * v;
```

Of course, an integer vector will only hold integer values, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no global overloaded operator of the form

`glm::vec3 operator*(int, const glm::vec3&)`

Does `v * 2` work by any chance? (A member function operator overload would suffice for that.)

Or perhaps even `2f * v`, which would then require the first parameter of the overloaded `*` operator to be a `float`?